# $e^{\ln(-2)} = -2$ but $\ln(-2) = \ln 2+i\pi$. How does this work?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I'm messing with exponential growth functions.  I noticed that I can write

$y(t)=y(0)\alpha^t$ as

$y(t)=y(0)e^{\ln(\alpha)t}$

(and then I can go ahead and replace $\ln(\alpha)$ with $\lambda$.)

But how do I handle when the $\alpha$ in $\ln(\alpha)$ is negative?  WolframAlpha simply evaluates

$e^{\ln(-2)}$ as $-2$

but how do I get avoid the whole negative number issue?

WolframAlpha also calls log the natural logarithm, which is confusing. :/

Comment: In the same spirit: $$1=\left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^{2\pi i}=e^{-4\pi^2}.$$

Comment: That's a good one. The fallacy is though that the double exponent rule, (a^b)^c = a^(bc) does not always hold true, if b and c are complex due to logarithmic branches. But who sees that...In fact, number 1 can be written in lots of e-power multiples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write any non negative number as an e-power as you did. In case the number is negative, keep the negative outside, so -e^ln(2)
The composition of inverse functions is the identity function x, only on their defined domains, so for lnx that means x>0

Comment: Oh cool.  I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks!

Comment: the only number that really cannot be written as a power of e is zero. That's because ln0 does not exist at all, not in real and not in complex

Answer (score 1):

With Euler's identity, $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+\sin\theta$. This is just a nice identity, proven to work for complex numbers.
Any complex number can be written then as :$$z=re^{i\theta}$$
where $r$ is its modulus.

Now take $\ln$ of that:
$$\ln z=\ln (r e^{i\theta})=\ln r+\ln e^{i\theta}=\ln r+i\theta $$

Now, because $e^{i\theta}=e^{i(\theta+2k\pi)}$, we have in general,
$$\ln z=\ln r+i(\theta+2k\pi)$$

Comment: Ah that's useful too.  Thanks!